# unity c# vuforia multiple virtual buttons

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

How to apply 2 or more Virtual buttons under the same class to call multiple animations from a single animator.

Below is for one button, How to add one more button in this

```
public class Vb_ball : MonoBehaviour, IVirtualButtonEventHandler
{
    public GameObject vbBtnObj;
    public Animator Ballanimation;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        vbBtnObj = GameObject.Find("Openbutton");
        vbBtnObj.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour>().RegisterEventHandler(this);
        Ballanimation.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    public void OnButtonPressed(VirtualButtonBehaviour vb)
    {
        Ballanimation.Play("Opn_close");
        Debug.Log("Button pressed");
    }

    public void OnButtonReleased(VirtualButtonBehaviour vb)
    {
        Ballanimation.Play("Static");
        Debug.Log("Button released");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I've Edited the below script which i got online and really forgot from where I got it. Which works